# How to convert IEnumerable<char> to string[] so I can use it with String.Join?

Tags: c#, string

How can I convert the `IEnumerable<char>` "nonLetters" to a `string[]` so that I can use it with String.Join?

```
string message = "This is a test message.";

var nonLetters = message.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x));

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} non-characters in \"{1}\" and they are: {2}", 
    nonLetters.Count(), 
    message,
    String.Join(", ", nonLetters.ToArray())
    );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string[] foo = nonLetters.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't actually care about using String.Join but only want the result, using **new string(char[])** is the simplest change:

```
string message = "This is a test message.";
var nonLetters = message.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x));
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} non-characters in \"{1}\" and they are: {2}",
     nonLetters.Count(),
     message,
     new string(nonLetters.ToArray()));
```

but for your example it is more efficient if you do it this way:

```
string message = "This is a test message.";
string nonLetters = new string(message.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x)).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} non-characters in \"{1}\" and they are: {2}",
     nonLetters.Length,
     message,
     nonLetters);
```

The reason this is more efficient is that the other example iterates your **where** iterator twice:  Once for the Count() call and the other time for the ToArray() call.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
string message = "This is a test message.";

var nonLetters = message.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x));

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} non-characters in \"{1}\" and they are: {2}", 
    nonLetters.Count(), 
    message,
    String.Join(", ", nonLetters.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
    );
```

All I've done is call `Select(x => x.ToString())` on nonLetters in the String.Join call. Seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
string result = new string(nonLetters.ToArray()); //convert to a string
```

I just realized you want a string[] and not a string:

```
string[] result = nonLetters.Select(c => new string(new[] { c })).ToArray();
```

Nasty.  But it works...

Comment: This doesn't produce a string[] as Edward requested.

Answer (score 1):

Just select a String instead of a Char for each of your non-letter.

```
String() nonLetters = message.Where(x => !Char.IsLetter(x))
                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that you only need to do that in the call to String.Join - with this code, the Count() call will end up converting each char to a string pointlessly. (Alternatively you could call ToList to only compute the results once.)

Comment: You're right, didn't think of the .Count() call. The most optimal solution would be to add the .ToArray() before the Console.WriteLine then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With [.NET 4 you have another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) for Join. As simple as:

```
var nonLettersJoined = string.Join(", ", message.Where(x => char.IsLetter(x)));
```

Saves you another `Select` and `ToArray` part. So should be slightly more efficient.. The `ToString` is called internally.